# reorder MySql table rows according to a given php array

Tags: php, mysql

I want to reorder table rows according to a given php array.

```
$table = $_POST["table"];
$rlist = json_decode( $_POST['b'], true );

foreach ($rlist as $value) {
    $i = array_search($value, $rlist);
    $i+=1;
    echo "<div>" . $i . "</div>";
}
```

This works fine. Result is 1 2 3 4 5 ...

But:

```
foreach ($rlist as $value) {
   $i = array_search($value, $rlist);
   $i+=1;
   try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE ' . $table. ' SET sort = :sort WHERE title = :title') ;
    $stmt->execute(array(
    ':sort' => $i,
    ':title' => $value,
    ));
    exit;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

This doesn't work completely. The result in the sort column is: 1 1 3 4 5...

Comment: What's the purpose of the "exit" statement in your loop? Doesn't it stops your loop after one iteration?

Comment: @Osuwariboy, you're right. Solved. You should place your comment as answer.

Comment: What if your `$_POST['table']` happens to be called `information_schema SET USER_PRIVILEGES.<column name> = <anything>, (etc. etc.) ;--`?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work as expected?

```
foreach ($rlist as $iPos => $value) {

   try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE ' . $table. ' SET sort = :sort WHERE title = :title') ;
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':sort' => $iPos + 1,
            ':title' => $value,
        ));
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an "exit" statement in the loop that prevents it from iterating. The corrected code should be:

```
foreach ($rlist as $value) {
   $i = array_search($value, $rlist);
   $i+=1;
   try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE ' . $table. ' SET sort = :sort WHERE title = :title') ;
    $stmt->execute(array(
    ':sort' => $i,
    ':title' => $value,
    ));

    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```